# Border around full background image

Tags: responsive-design, border

I am trying to make a border/frame around a full screen background picture.

I could make it using border but I could not create a space between the edge and the frame. https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/44798/299518/TieMyM2f0EXsUsK/frame.png

Also the second thing is to create a hole on the bottom side of the pic.

If you guys have any advises, I would really appreciate.

Thanks for you help,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you about the hole but you can set padding and  magrin  with css to your image to create the space between the end of image and the border and the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if thats what you mean, but maybe try something like this (tested on chrome)

```
<div id="cont">
 <div id="break"></div>
</div>

#cont {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
}

#break {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 100%;
    bottom: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2bph38qh/